# Google Nearby Messages API strategies

Tags: android, google-nearby

Hi I am developing an android app,to send messages via google nearby messages API,but I am confused what strategy to choose,can anyone please explain the differences,or in which range approximately this options are working.Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your use case is to send messages via Nearby, you should consider using `DISTANCE_TYPE_DEFAULT` and `DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT` based on how far do you want the other device in order for it to receive the message.

Comment: Thx,do you know approximate distance for each option?

Comment: Since Nearby uses Wifi and Bluetooth for searching for Nearby devices, for Bluetooth it'll be approximately 10 meters, for Wifi how it works is, the devices that can see the same Wifi Network as your device are considered as nearby devices, can't be exactly sure what the distance will be in that case.

Comment: It also uses Ultrasound for finding Nearby Devices, the way it works is - the device publishing will emit ultrasounds and the subscribing devices if are able to listen to this Ultrasound are in a close proximity and are considered Nearby.

Comment: So I'd say the `DISTANCE_TYPE_DEFAULT` would use Wifi and can reach a farther distance to search for Nearby Devices, while `DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT` would use Bluetooth and/or Ultrasound for the same but for devices in a lesser proximity.

Comment: @hsm59 is it bad practice to subscribe or publish in service?

Comment: You won't be able to run Nearby using a Service, since it requires the device publishing and the device that is subscribing both on foreground. Check this for more information -  [Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/developer-guidelines)